# How to read multiple multivariate csv files to train Transformer

Tags: csv, tensor, transformer-model

I have data which is (3 x m x time x n) dimensional (m= number of csv files, time= timesteps, n= number of features)(pardon me, I cannot provide more information about the data). To be more clear, I have 3 folders that each contain m csv file that are (time x n) dimensional. I need to read them to use for my transformer model. Think about it as 3 being 3 color channel of images and (time x n) reperesents the matrix of each image and m is the total number of images.

I cannot use concatenate or other merging files methods as they will loose the time dependency of my data, so I need a better approach. I was thinking about creating m tensors of size (3 x time x n) but don't know how.
Could please share your ideas if you have any suggestions?